# Select Last Record In One-Too-Many Relationships

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, join, indexing

I'm having trouble formatting a query to return a team of people whilst joining their latest record from another table where available.

I've been through a number of examples on SO but have been unable to find one specific to MS Access 2007 that suits my requirements.

The schemas are as follows:

**dbo_ds_staff**

```
id
first_name
last_name
```

**dbo_ds_team_staff_member**

```
id
team_id
staff_id
start_date
end_date
```

**dbo_ds_team_leader**

```
id
team_id
staff_id
start_date
end_date
```

**ct_pm_Diagnostic**

```
id
staff_id
outcome_id
Added
```

**ct_pm_Outcome**

```
id
outcome
```

I'm wanting to return in the query the staff id, first_name, last_name and outcome (if available).

I've tried the following but it returns all the records for the team not just the latest diagnostic:

```
SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name, o.Outcome 
    FROM ((SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name 
        FROM ((dbo_ds_staff AS s 
            INNER JOIN dbo_ds_team_staff_member AS tsm ON s.id=tsm.staff_id) 
            INNER JOIN dbo_ds_team_leader AS tl ON tsm.team_id=tl.team_id) 
            WHERE tl.staff_id = 26928 And tsm.start_date < Now() And (tsm.end_date >= Now() Or tsm.end_date Is Null) And tl.start_date < Now() And (tl.end_date >= Now() Or tl.end_date Is Null) 
            GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name) as s 
    LEFT JOIN ct_pm_Diagnostic AS d ON s.id=d.StaffId) 
    LEFT JOIN ct_pm_Outcome AS o ON d.OutcomeId = o.OutcomeId 
    ORDER BY s.first_name, s.last_name
```

Could anyone help with how to only return the latest diagnostic result based on the `Added` field in from the table `ct_pm_Diagnostic`? My research indicates that I need to be using the MAX function on `Added` along with another `Group By` condition but I struggling to figure out how to utilse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to get the lasted added date from diagnistic per staff member:

```
SELECT  d.StaffID, MAX(Added) AS MaxAdded
FROM    ct_pm_Diagnostic
GROUP BY d.StaffID;
```

You would then need to join the results of this query back to `ct_pm_Diagnostic` to filter it just for the latest record for each staff member:

```
SELECT  d.*
FROM    ct_pm_Diagnostic AS d
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  d.StaffID, MAX(Added) AS Added
            FROM    ct_pm_Diagnostic
            GROUP BY d.StaffID
        ) AS MaxD
            ON MaxD.StaffID = d.StaffID
            AND MaxD.Added = d.Added;
```

I think you can then add this back to your original query as follows (Untested):

```
SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name, o.Outcome 
    FROM ((SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name 
        FROM ((dbo_ds_staff AS s 
            INNER JOIN dbo_ds_team_staff_member AS tsm ON s.id=tsm.staff_id) 
            INNER JOIN dbo_ds_team_leader AS tl ON tsm.team_id=tl.team_id) 
            WHERE tl.staff_id = 26928 And tsm.start_date < Now() And (tsm.end_date >= Now() Or tsm.end_date Is Null) And tl.start_date < Now() And (tl.end_date >= Now() Or tl.end_date Is Null) 
            GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name) as s 
    LEFT JOIN (ct_pm_Diagnostic AS d 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT d.StaffID, MAX(Added) AS Added
                    FROM ct_pm_Diagnostic
                    GROUP BY d.StaffID) AS MaxD 
            ON MaxD.StaffID = d.StaffID AND MaxD.Added = d.Added)
        ON s.id=d.StaffId) 
    LEFT JOIN ct_pm_Outcome AS o ON d.OutcomeId = o.OutcomeId 
    ORDER BY s.first_name, s.last_name
```

---

**EDIT**

I tried to give the least verbose join method possible, but it looks like Access doesn't support it, I can't see any reason why the below wouldn't work:

```
SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name, o.Outcome 
    FROM ((SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name 
        FROM ((dbo_ds_staff AS s 
            INNER JOIN dbo_ds_team_staff_member AS tsm ON s.id=tsm.staff_id) 
            INNER JOIN dbo_ds_team_leader AS tl ON tsm.team_id=tl.team_id) 
            WHERE tl.staff_id = 26928 And tsm.start_date < Now() And (tsm.end_date >= Now() Or tsm.end_date Is Null) And tl.start_date < Now() And (tl.end_date >= Now() Or tl.end_date Is Null) 
            GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name) as s 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.*
                FROM ct_pm_Diagnostic AS d
                    INNER JOIN
                    (   SELECT  d.StaffID, MAX(Added) AS Added
                        FROM    ct_pm_Diagnostic
                        GROUP BY d.StaffID
                    ) AS MaxD
                        ON MaxD.StaffID = d.StaffID
                        AND MaxD.Added = d.Added) AS d
        ON s.id=d.StaffId) 
    LEFT JOIN ct_pm_Outcome AS o ON d.OutcomeId = o.OutcomeId 
    ORDER BY s.first_name, s.last_name
```

If it still doesn't work you may be best off saving this query:

```
SELECT  d.*
FROM    ct_pm_Diagnostic AS d
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  d.StaffID, MAX(Added) AS Added
            FROM    ct_pm_Diagnostic
            GROUP BY d.StaffID
        ) AS MaxD
            ON MaxD.StaffID = d.StaffID
            AND MaxD.Added = d.Added;
```

As something like `LatestDiagnostic`, then you can just replace `ct_pm_Diagnostic` with `LatestDiagnostic` in your original query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I understand the theory here now. I'm unfortunately still getting a `JOIN expression not supported` error with no indication of where the error is.

Comment: That's great thanks, the edited version worked with a couple of tweaks. Really appreciate you time!

Comment: I'm using this method on another query which has three filters to get latest records from a number of tables. Is it best practice to save each individual query and reference them within a 'mater' query or just have them all in one query? Thanks

Comment: I honestly could not tell you about best practices in Access. I know that it doesn't handle complex queries particularly well, so saving them as a separate query can help this, but I'd say do what every you will find easiest to maintain.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone with storing the queries separately as it seems to be easier for me to work through the logic. I know what you're saying about Access and complex queries, useless!